# How can I check if windows features are activated using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4

My researches revealed, that I can find out the state (diabled/enabled) of the windows features using the following command on DISM:

```
dism /online /get-features | more
```

With this command I get a list (sorry for German language):

[image: windows features]

I am able to execute the dism-command via C# using class `Process()`. My next task is to parse this list into an List of KeyValuePairs and compare the state of my required features. But this seems to be inconvenient and error-prone.

Is there any stable way to check if specific windows features are activated?

(I am using .NET Framework 4.5)

I want to activate features for:
 - Windows Server 2008
 - Windows Server 2008 R2
 - Windows 7
 - Windows 8
 - Windows 8.1
 - Windows Server 2012

Comment: There's plenty of pieces of example code for making WMI queries from .NET. There's a WMI class called [Win32_ServerFeature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280268(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thank you very much for your answer. I forgot to list my target operating systems where I want to activate the features. I have updated my question. The `Win32_ServerFeature` seems only to work on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2. Because of that, Win32_ServerFeature is only suitable as a part for my problem.

Comment: Well, there's also [`Win32_OptionalFeature`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309383(v=vs.85).aspx). Basically, if you're wanting to find out OS information and there's not something built into .NET to directly support it, the next place you ought to be thinking about is the WMI classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the class I used that I got from an example somewhere (most likely SO):

```
        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_ServerFeature");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            string featureName = (string)objMO.Properties["Name"].Value;

            //add to my list
            InstalledFeatures.Add(featureName);

            if (BadRoles.Contains(featureName))
                DetectedBadRoles.Add(featureName);
        }
```